# Extension to my MySQL query. Need to compare values from different row and column

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

[image]

I want to select Code and Number from it and this is visualization of my query:

[image]

And this is query:

```
SELECT Code,Number,(1894 - Limit1) AS spread1,(Limit2 - 1894) AS spread2 
FROM MyTable WHERE Name="John" AND 600>=L1 AND 600<=L2 
AND 1894>=Limit1 AND 1894<=Limit2
```

As noted in picture this query returns two values and I need just one. So I should compare **spread2** from **row1** with **spread1** from **row2** and take Code and Number of bigger spread and in this case it's `spread2`.

Why am I comparing **spread2** from row1 and **spread1** from row2 is because they are overlapping their selves. So, I'm comparing spreads within that overlap:

[image]

With my query from above I can get **only one or two rows as a result, never more**. Why? Because table is created that way. If one row appears as a result I won't be needed any comparison, what means that I have single Code and Number.

So, in bottom line, I need extension to my query to do the thing mentioned above.

What I've tried is to add:

```
ORDER BY (spread2,spread1) DESC LIMIT 1
```

and I'm sure that it does not comparing values as I want rather vales from the same row.

Comment: Why are you comparing spread2 with spread1? What if you had 3 rows in your results? Additionally, `take Code and Number of bigger spread` note that 3006 > 1144 so you should return the row with 3006, right?

Comment: Your picture does not make sense to me.  Could you provide some explanation with it?

Comment: Why the `1144` and `3006` are not considered?

Comment: try `ORDER BY LEAST(Limit2 - 1894, 1894 - Limit1) DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @MostyMostacho I've updated my question for you.

Comment: @ypercube I've tried that but, as I've said, I'm not sure that I'm comparing the right values. So, if you have something else in your mind, you're welcome!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Pictures pasted above are just visualization of my table, query and scenario. They're just simplified and minimized version of an actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

For Value1 = 600 and Value2 = 1894:

```
SELECT number,code,(spread2)AS spread FROM(SELECT number,code,@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS RowNumber, (1894 - Limit1) AS spread1,(Limit2 - 1894) AS spread2
FROM MyTable JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r WHERE name="John" AND 600>=L1 AND 600<=L2 AND 1894>=Limit1 AND 1894<=Limit2)temp WHERE RowNumber=1
UNION
SELECT number,code,(spread1)AS spread FROM(SELECT number,code,@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS RowNumber, (1894 - Limit1) AS spread1,(Limit2 - 1894) AS spread2
FROM MyTable JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r WHERE name="John" AND 600>=L1 AND 600<=L2 AND 1894>=Limit1 AND 1894<=Limit2)temp WHERE RowNumber=2
ORDER BY spread DESC limit 1
```

When Value1 = 950 and Value2 = 2400:

```
SELECT number,code,(spread2)AS spread FROM(SELECT number,code,@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS RowNumber,(2400 - Limit1) AS spread1,(Limit2 - 2400) AS spread2
FROM MyTable JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r WHERE name="John" AND 950>=L1 AND 950<=L2 AND 2400>=Limit1 AND 2400<=Limit2)temp WHERE RowNumber=1
UNION
SELECT number,code,(spread1)AS spread FROM(SELECT number,code,@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS RowNumber,(2400 - Limit1) AS spread1,(Limit2 - 2400) AS spread2
FROM MyTable JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r WHERE name="John" AND 950>=L1 AND 950<=L2 AND 2400>=Limit1 AND 2400<=Limit2)temp WHERE RowNumber=2
ORDER BY spread DESC limit 1
```

And it also works when I get one row as a result.